# Can we use the resource of library module in App module?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, navigation, resources

I am using the lib and app module in one of my projects. I am in a dilemma to use the lib resource file (`values>nav_graph>navigation.xml`) in my app module. Is there any possibility to use it. The navigation file has the action of all the fragments which is used in the lib module.

Any suggestions/solutions would be appreciated!!!

Comment: Yes, you can use lib resource file unless they are not private

Answer (score 0):

Yes You can use public library resources in your app module.
For example:

I have one library which have strings resources `strings.xml`

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name" translatable="false">AudioLib</string>
    <string name="save">Save</string>
    <string name="paused">Paused</string>
    <string name="recording">Recording</string>
    <string name="playing">Playing</string>
</resources>
```

Now If I want to get save attribute from that, I can use like this in your activity:

```
resources.getString(com.audiolib.lib.R.string.save)
```

so import libray's R.java instead of your app module R.java

Comment: How can i use navigation.xml which is present in library module. Can  we able to add in main_activity.xml in app module? the navigation.xml will be used with app:navGraph="navigation/navigation" properties. But whenever we are adding it we  are getting an error.

Comment: val graph = inflater.inflate(R.navigation.nav_graph) - might be you can use with code like this instead of xml